# BattleFront (2015) Dell Latitude Driver Issue

Tags: drivers

Here is my question: I recently tried to play Battlefront (2015) on my Dell Latitude e6500, but when I try to start up the demo I get one warning saying this:[image: Driver Issue]

The if I click on ok I get this:
[image: DirecX Issue]
Thank you for your time and consideration.
Also as a side note sorry if this is the wrong place to post this, but if you can please direct me to where I can ask this question.

Comment: you have not asked a question

Comment: The question is implicit - the answer is that machine is too old to run that game.